# Azure Function App with QueueTrigger fails to connect to Storage account with VNet configuration

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-storage-account, vnet

We are trying restrict public access from an Azure Storage account. We only want an App service (Web API) and a Function app to communicate to the Azure Storage account. We created a VNet and a Subnet inside it; moved the App service and the Function app into the same App service plan; and configured both the App service and Function app within the same VNet/Subnet. In the Azure Storage account's Networking tab, we restricted access to the VNet/Subnet as shown below.

[image: Storage Account Networking tab]

The function app uses a Queue Trigger and the Azure queue exists within the same storage account we are trying to lock down.

Our situation is that the App service plan is managing to connect to the storage account (via the Shared access keys). However, the function app is not even picking up the items from the queue. This means that the function app code is never hit (first logs are not written in the Application insights and the actual communication with the Storage account via the Shared access keys is never reached). This is very likely related to the new network changes, because when the storage account is made public again, the function app works again, as expected.

This is a bit strange, because the app service and the function app have the same VNet / Subnet configuration. Our previous Function app version was consumption based and we migrated into an App Service plan based function app to be able to manage this.

Do function apps require a different configuration from app services? Particularly ones with QueueTriggers? Does the QueueTrigger not allow access in such a way?

Comment: I'm having similar issues. I wonder what was the eventual fix for your issue if you don't  mind sharing.

Comment: I never found a solution for this. I ended up having the Queue in another storage account with public access. The storage account with the sensitive information has been locked down. The usual communication with the private storage account via the shared access keys is still possible (thanks to the vnet/subnet configuration) - it is the QueueTrigger aspect that does not work.

Comment: https://www.michaelscollier.com/azure-functions-with-private-endpoints/  
This article helped me solve my issue.